# Problems with Rake and Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, rubygems, rake, rakefile

I have been trying to run rake but it seems that ever since I updated ruby gems rake is failing.

This morning I ran:

```
gem update --system
```

And ever since, rake has been failing with the following error:

```
$ rake db:migrate                                                                                 
rake aborted!
undefined method `specifications' for "/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1":String
/home/cknadler/projects/ecommerce/Rakefile:7:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I have been reading about this problem and it seems that there is a problem with rake 0.9.x that breaks rails but when I check my rake version, I am running 0.8.7:

```
$ rake --version                                                                                    
rake, version 0.8.7
```

I have tried uninstalling rake and reinstalling it, using bundler, etc and at this point I am pretty stuck. Thanks in advance.

Edit:

My Rakefile (located in my app root directory)

```
# Add your own tasks in files placed in lib/tasks ending in .rake,
# for example lib/tasks/capistrano.rake, and they will automatically be available to Rake.

require File.expand_path('../config/application', __FILE__)
require 'rake'

Ecommerce::Application.load_tasks
```

Comment: hm, I was going to suggest the 0.8.7 thing, but looks like you already tried that

Comment: Yeah, I have been reading posts here and on other sites and it seems that usually when people have this problem they just need to downgrade to a lower version of rake. As far as I can tell, either I don't understand how to fully remove a gem or there is something else wrong that I am not seeing.

Comment: if you do a "gem list --local" (that's 2 dashes) do you have more than one version of Rake installed? If so, you can do "gem uninstall rake", and there's a flag I don't remember that allows you to specify which version you want to uninstall. Something simple like "-v" and a version number or something.

Comment: I tried gem uninstall rake and then reinstall with the command: 
gem install rake -v 0.8.7, this worked but didn't fix my error when trying to use rake.

Comment: Yes, using bundler version 1.0.13.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest using the bundled binary version of rake to avoid this issue.

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

If you installed your bundle using binstubs (`bundle install --binstubs`) then you can also use the bin version of rake which is equivalent to the `bundle exec rake` command:

```
bin/rake db:migrate
```

P.S: I would also recommend using [RVM](https://rvm.io) instead of installing Ruby using sudo for all users. This allows you to keep more modular ruby and gem installation.

Comment: When using the command:
bundle exec rake db:migrate, rake prints out the same error as above. As for RVM I am currently using RVM version: 1.6.16. Is there a different approach I should be taking to this because I am using RVM?

Comment: From your error message it seems that you are using a system installation of Ruby(`/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1`), not an RVM one. I would recommend ensuring that you have properly installed Ruby via RVM and that you are using that version of Ruby and not the system version. Also, would you paste the relevant part of your Rakefile?

Comment: I pasted my entire rakefile above as it was short and I didn't know what you meant by 'relevant part'. As far as RVM goes I am reinstaling ruby 1.9.2-p180 and will see if that helps.

Comment: Wow, it must have been RVM. After I reinstalled ruby using RVM and refollowed the rvm installation documentation, all I had to do was type bundle update and everything started working again. Thank you so much for your help, now I can get back to work!

Answer (score 1):

You should remove rake 0.9.x (you may have 0.9.2 installed) by doing

```
gem uninstall rake -v=0.9.2
```

And then run bundle update

```
bundle update
```

Hope that helps.